# Get specific fields only elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I need some help regarding querying in elasticsearch.

So basically, the api looks something like this:

```
{
"took": 58,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 3,
"successful": 3,
"skipped": 0,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 1020900,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
{
   "_index": "index-20192029",
   "_type": "_doc",
   "_id": "urn:22291760",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
         "user_id": 1234567,
         "document": [
         {
              "documentType": "application/pdf",
              "documentUrl": "http://somethingxyz1234.pdf"
         },
        {
             "documentType": "application/xml",
             "documentUrl": "http://somethingxyz1234.xml"
        }
], .....
```

How do I only get the url that is an xml?

I tried doing

```
"_source": ["user_id", "document.documentType", "document.documentUrl"],
"query": {
     "bool": {
          "match": { "document.documentType" :"application/xml"} 
     }
}
```

But that also included the pdf.
I just want the documentUrl to give only the url that's xml.

Thanks

Comment: The "document" is nested type?

Answer (score 0):

If document is nested you can use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html) to get the document query match.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "document",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "document.documentType": {
            "value": "application/pdf"
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
   "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "pv36jIIB-X7q7ErxEhyg",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "document" : [
            {
              "documentType" : "application/pdf",
              "documentUrl" : "http://somethingxyz1234.pdf"
            },
            {
              "documentType" : "application/xml",
              "documentUrl" : "http://somethingxyz1234.xml"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "document" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.6931471,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "test",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "pv36jIIB-X7q7ErxEhyg",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "document",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 0.6931471,
                  "_source" : {
                    "documentType" : "application/pdf",
                    "documentUrl" : "http://somethingxyz1234.pdf"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```